# Z3 OCaml API: difference between mk_solver_s, mk_solver and mk_simple_solver

Tags: ocaml, z3, smt

Good afternoon,

I am using Z3 OCaml bindings to verify properties on rational values. I noted vast differences when I initialized my solver using `mk_solver_s ctx "QF_NRA"` and `mk_simple_solver` (context here is `let ctx = mk_context [("model","true");("unsat_core","true")]`).

> Or what can be sat/unsat. Assuming you don't get a "unknown symbol" kind of issue, in general there should be no difference in sat/unsat answers, but performance can vary depending on logic selection.

More specifically, I perform branch and bound exploration on possible activations for a neural network. Activation here is to be understood as whether the input of a certain function is positive or negative; result of this function then yield different behaviours for the neural network and gives some linear constraints on the inputs.

The neural network linear part is written as an SMT formula. Then, each time I meet a possible activation, I can check if it is possible or not according to previous already met activations. If one activation is possible, the relevant constraint are added to the solver stack and proceed. If two activations are possible, the solver is cloned, and I proceed with the two solvers with an additional constraint each.

By using `mk_solver_s ctx QF_NRA`, I had much more possible activations than with `mk_simple_solver ctx` (actually, `2^n` where `n` is the number of neurons); models obtained with the first one were not taking into account some constraints I added. For instance, I had

```
(> |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_1| (/ 1.0 2.0))
(< |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_1| 2.0)
(> |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_0| (/ 1.0 2.0))
(< |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_0| 2.0)
```

in my solver stack, but one of my models shown

```
(define-fun |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_0| () Real
  0.0)
(define-fun |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_1| () Real
  0.0)
```

Changing only the solver initialization function remove this behaviour.

The documentation (here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/ml/Z3.Solver.html) lacks any explanation regarding this; maybe I am not looking at the good place.
I was wondering what are the differences between the following functions:

- `mk_simple_solver`
- `mk_solver_s` (which seems to accept only theories string, but it would seem regarding this https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1035#issuecomment-303160975 that it actually accepts a whole lot of tactics, which I am not sure how to use)
- `mk_solver`

What are the "defaults" that `mk_simple_solver` sets and `mk_solver_s` does not do?

I would be eager to do a pull request for enhancing the OCaml API, I am not quite sure where to look at to begin with.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can answer some of these questions by looking at their implementations:

```ml
let mk_solver ctx logic =
    match logic with
    | None -> Z3native.mk_solver ctx
    | Some x -> Z3native.mk_solver_for_logic ctx x

let mk_solver_s ctx logic = mk_solver ctx (Some (Symbol.mk_string ctx logic))
let mk_simple_solver = Z3native.mk_simple_solver
```

So, the string in `mk_solver_s` lets you pick which logic you want. (Not "theories" which are different. Logics can be thought of as combinations of theories, see the SMTLib site for details: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories.shtml vs http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/logics.shtml)

So, `mk_solver_s` is exactly the same as `mk_solver`, except it allows you to start with a given logic. (The logic selection mostly matters as to which symbols are available in the solver, as some terms only make sense in certain logics. For instance, you cannot use quantifiers in any logic that declares itself to be quantifier-free, etc.)

You said you noticed "vast differences" using these, but did not elaborate what those differences are? You mean performance? Or what can be `sat`/`unsat`. Assuming you don't get a "unknown symbol" kind of issue, in general there should be no difference in `sat/unsat` answers, but performance can vary depending on logic selection. (For instance, picking a difference-logic can make a huge impact on constraints that don't need anything else.) But without details it's hard to opine.

Hope this gets you started. Sometimes the best thing to do is to look at the source code itself!

Comment: The OCaml docstrings are lacking in some areas - when in doubt check the C API, which is the reference for all the other APIs, e.g. https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga6339c11a9dc478400444cebd82847c2a .

Comment: I have given additional details in the original post :)

Comment: Looks like you're suggesting you get a different set of models if you initialize the solver differently? (i.e., what one shows as a model, the other says is not?) If that's the case, this should be reported as a bug: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues I would expect performance differences, but the set of models should be exactly the same.